# RTF field Parsing

Tags: rtf, api

I am trying to Parse the content for a RTF Field as same as it done when we move from   Design tag to source tag, after we parse the content, same will be used to update component through API call

How can I specifically decode the content other than HTML Tags

Comment: What exactly do you need to do, are you talking about applying the XSLT manually?

Comment: Yes, I have an input  content something like this `& < > <a href="&">Testing</a>`  where I need to parse the content as same as Tridion does `&amp; &lt; &gt; <a href="&amp;">Testing</a>`

Comment: I think the question is about replicating the XSLT rich text filter behavior that happens in the CME but when using the Core Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select the **Source** tab in an RTF field, the Tridion GUI applies an XSLT against the XHTML that exists; this causes the escaping of the HTML you seem to desire.

The same action is undertaken when you select **Save** in the GUI.

The XSLT is located in the Schema as a property of the RTF field - you will see a button titled `Edit Formatting Features` and the XSLT is prompted when you click this and then select the `Filtering XSLT` tab.

You simply need to apply the same XSLT (which you'd probably need to hand manage between where your original input is and the Tridion Schema - although in my experience this will VERY rarely be updated).

**Where** and **how** you apply that will depend on *where* you are needing to do the transformation (*there's a very high degree of guesswork here as your question is far from clear and would benefit from a lot more context of the actual requirement*)